# Why draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) is not called without empty draw(_ rect: CGRect)?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics, uigraphicscontext

When i override **draw(_ rect: CGRect)** and leave it empty, then it happens that  draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) got called. And circle is painted.

[image]

Here is the code. I just assigned SpecialView class to view in IB.

```
class SpecialView : UIView {
   override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
   }
  
   override func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {
            UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)
            let p = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(0,0,100,100))
            UIColor.blue.setFill()
            p.fill()
            UIGraphicsPopContext()
   }

}
```

But when i do not override **draw(_ rect: CGRect)**, and just leave the code as below in code snippet:

```
 class SpecialView : UIView {
 
   override func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {
            UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)
            let p = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(0,0,100,100))
            UIColor.blue.setFill()
            p.fill()
            UIGraphicsPopContext()
   }
}
```

The  **draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext)** function is not called. And circle is not got painted.
[image]

Do you know why?

Comment: I feel I've seen this code before, somewhere...

Comment: @matt of course, in your book! thank you very much!

Comment: :) Let's not turn the question into an advertisement; that would be wrong.

Comment: @matt ok, but sorry that i did say that i wrote this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layers are very lazy about drawing. They do not draw unless you tell them that they need to. So, you could solve the problem here by explicitly telling the layer `setNeedsDisplay`.

However, *views* are a little more proactive. They redraw themselves automatically under certain circumstances, like when they first appear. Since this layer is the underlying layer of a view, you can get the layer to participate in that automatic redrawing if you can get the view to redraw itself automatically.

But (and this is the important part) the runtime, for the sake of efficiency, assumes that if a view has *no* `drawRect` implementation, it does not need automatic redrawing.

So there's your answer:

1. Normally, a layer would not redraw at all until you tell it to.
2. By providing a `drawRect` implementation, even though it is empty, you tell the *view* to redraw itself automatically when needed.
3. This is the view's underlying layer, so it is redrawn with the view.

Comment: All of that information _is_ in the book you got the example from. You probably just haven't read far enough. The Six Blue Circles example is in Chapter 2, but layer drawing is not explained until Chapter 3.

Comment: Thank you for your help! now it is more clear situation for me!

Comment: @Ninja The key sentence from Chapter 3 is: "If a layer is a view's underlying layer,... you will probably want to implement `draw(_:)` anyway, leaving that implementation empty. The reason is that this causes the layer to redisplay itself at appropriate moments.... If you're drawing a view entirely by drawing to its underlying layer directly, and if you want the underlying layer to be redisplayed automatically when the view is told to redraw itself, you should implement `draw(_:)` to do nothing."

Comment: @matt we can also set `contentMode` to `.redraw` instead of overriding `drawRect`. is there any issues with doing that?